# Python Regex DataFrame match

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, iteration

I have a DataFrame and I would like to perform a sorting if the match between my regex and the name of one of the lines of this DataFrame matches.
Is there an option in the "re" library to help me?
I try with this piece of code but without success
Thank you in advance for your answers

```
regex = r"D.*cube"

for row in range(len(df)):
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        
        if df.iloc[row, col] == regex:
          #treatment...
          .............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want

```
pattern = r"D.*cube"

for row in range(len(df)):
    for col in range(len(df.columns)):
        
        if re.match(pattern, df.iloc[row, col]):
          #treatment...
          .............
```

Comment: Thank you Nicholas for your reply.
Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I end up with this error...  

----> 6         if re.match(pattern, dfc.iloc[row, col]):
189     """Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning
    190     a Match object, or None if no match was found."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
    192 
    193 def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Problem solved, thanks to your Nicholas solution. I also had to force the comparasion by indicating :  str(dfc.iloc [row, col])) 
Again, thank you very much :D